# When a fight is a personal settlement

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

Imagine you are fighting someone over a bad problem. A friend tries to interfere. You are going to get even with the guy because of what he did in the past. You want to prevent the friend from interfering and ask them not to say or do anything because it is a personal matter. I was wondering if someone could let me know if in the self-made sentence below the bold word is natural (for indicating that you are going to get even with the guy / get settled)? If not, then what shall I use to convey exactly the same message:

> - Please don't interfere. This is a personal **settlement**.

Comment: I imagine that *It's personal* would get the point across quite well...

Answer (score 4):

You could use

> This is a personal affair.
>   This is a personal matter.
>   This is my personal business.
>   This does not involve you.

to indicate to your friend should stay away, not meddle and you will deal with it yourself.

If you use

> This is a personal settlement.

a settlement usually occurs at the end of a process and in terms of *legalese* usually implies a monetary payment.

Answer (score 0):

This is personal.

This is just between him and me.

This is just between me and him. (More colloquial).

This is a personal matter.

This is a personal matter between him and me.